# Browser support of <img> width and height for minimizing CLS

Tags: html, css

Currently Lighthouse/Google PageSpeed asks to set image width and height attributes for minimizing Commulative Layout Shift.

So as I can see simple solution, which works and has no LightHouse issues looks like this:

```css
img {
  display: block; // optional
  width: 100%; // not max-width, in some places we have to scale up image currently
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="/puppy.jpg" width="600" height="400" />
```

If I check the solution with Slow 3G network throttling it works perfect in latest browsers. (https://codepen.io/frenchrabbit/pen/poNXOxB)

The question is about browser support, I don't know how to check this on caniuse.
I see that CLS problem for this solutions solved in 2020 with "elegant solution" adding aspect-ratio: attr(width)/attr(height) in browser inner stylesheet.
I would like to know which versions of browsers supports this solutions. And also if some very old user agents have img attributes width/height priority over css width/height (for some reason I remember that it was the problem why I stopped using attributes for responsive sites).